# Execute command inside first directory of each matched result

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am working at a client who has a project where code is a mixture of different source control systems. So a layout might be like this

```
project/a/.svn
       /a/subfolder/.svn
       /b/.hg
       /c/subproject/.svn
       /d/.hg
```

So I am trying to put together a simple command that when executed from the **project** folder will run the appropriate hg/svn command in each project i.e:

```
pushd a/
svn up
popd
pushd b/
hg pull
popd
:
```

Since the client has many such projects, I would appreciate not having to hardcode the folder structure in a script. Instead I am looking for a solution similar to **find -exec** where the **svn/hg** commands are automatically executed on each first level of match (i.e. **svn up** is run in the **project/a** folder but not in **project/a/subfolder**). How can such a command be constructed ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea:

```
find /project -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name .svn -execdir svn up \; \
    -o -name .hg -execdir hg pull \; \)
```

Edit: perhaps something like

```
find /project \( -execdir test -d {}/.svn \; -execdir sh -c \
    'cd {} && svn update' \; -o -execdir test -d {}/.hg \; \
    -execdir sh -c 'cd {} && hg pull' \; \) -prune
```

Comment: Great although "maxdepth" seams to work on the search level rather than on the result level (i.e. in the above example /c/subproject/ also contains a subversion repo which then has depth 3 from the root). What I want to do is to execute a svn/hg command on the first folder I encounter that is a repo, this folder may be arbitrary nested down).

Comment: Try the edited version and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, this works as it should (the commands are now executed in all the correct directories). The only issue left is that it finds the same directory multiple times (executing svn/hg updates is a rather time consuming operation). I wonder if its somehow possible to throw in a unique option.

Comment: Hmm, hopefully 3rd time's the charm.

Comment: thats it ;) - thanks a allot, I must get more into the power of "find"